# Changing style color via JavaScript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have been trying to change the style color of an input field when a certain option is selected but it is not working. I have tried both onclick and oninput but to no avail. I suspect the issue lies with {{ type }} or == 'Buy'.

```
function changeColor () {
    var transaction_type = document.getElementById('buysell');
    var option_user_selection = transaction_type.options[ transaction_type.selectedIndex ].text;
    if (option_user_selection == 'Buy') {
        document.getElementById('costb').style.color = '#006400';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('costb').style.color = '#DC143C';
    }
}
<div class="transaction_type">
     <p>Transaction Type:</p>
     <select style="font-size:16px" class="form-select" id='buysell' required>
           {% for type in form.transaction_type %}
               <option>{{ type }}</option>
           {% endfor %}
     </select>
</div>
<div>
  <p>Cost Basis ($):</p>
  {{ form.cost_basis }}
</div>
```

forms.py

```
transaction_choices = [
    ('BUY', 'Buy'),
    ('SELL', 'Sell'),
]
transaction_type = forms.CharField(
    max_length=4,
    widget=forms.Select(
        choices=transaction_choices,
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-select',
            'name': 'transaction_type',
            'id': 'floatingTransaction',
            'oninput': 'changeColor();'
        })
)

cost_basis = forms.DecimalField(
    min_value = 0,
    widget = forms.NumberInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'name': 'cost_basis',
            'id': 'costb',
        })
)
```

[Rendered Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEGOt.jpg)

Comment: Could you show what your rendered `<select>` element looks like?

Comment: There is no _costb_ as _cost_basis_ isn't used anywhere.

Comment: `console.log(option_user_selection, option_user_selection == 'Buy' )` is it what you think it is?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I edited the post with the rendered <select> element, it's under select element.

Comment: @TGrif My bad, I didn't include it under the post initially.

Comment: @nicholas5538 Sorry, I meant the rendered HTML. The result of your Django template.

Comment: Haha, no mate. The actual HTML **code**. Currently you have a loop with `<option>{{ type }}</option>` in your code, which will be transformed into multiple `option` elements. But what I can see from your screenshot is that the `<select>` element is empty. Meaning that your loop is probably not working as you'd expect.